# Getting data from JSON file value is 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, json, global-variables

I'm trying get values from **[JSON](http://db.tt/5tD8xS7C)** file, the data stored in form of array.. Here is the code:

**JS:**

```
var initDate = new Date("7/9/2013");
var diffDays = 0;
var timeS;

function taqvimSingleDate() {
    // Calculation of Dates difference
    var currDate = new Date();
    diffDays = Math.floor((currDate.getTime() - initDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    $.getJSON('allData.json', function(data) {
        if (data != '' || data != undefined) {
            var addTohtml = '';
            addTohtml += '<td>' +data[diffDays].date_g+ '</td>';
            $('#singleDate').html(addTohtml);

            // Display appropriate time according to location (01 or 02 etc.)
            switch(getCity) {
            case '01': $('#sahari').html(data[diffDays].sahar_1);
                       timeS = data[diffDays].sahar_1;
                break;
            case '02': $('#sahari').html(data[diffDays].sahar_2);
                       timeS = data[diffDays].sahar_2;
                break;
            case '03': $('#sahari').html(data[diffDays].sahar_3);
                       timeS = data[diffDays].sahar_3;
                break;
            case '04': $('#sahari').html(data[diffDays].sahar_4);
                       timeS = data[diffDays].sahar_4;
                break;
            }
        } else {alert("Database is undefined/empty!");}
    });
}
alert(timeS);
```

The result of element `#sahari` is correct displayed (according to the value of getCity), but problem is my `timeS` variable is **undefined** and I'm stuck here. How to pass the value of `#sahari` correctly to `timeS` variable?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: @SLaks any alternative solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your value is stored in `timeS`, but you cannot use it at that point in time. It is only available after your callback went through sucessfully. Call a function that is processing your desired variable within your callback function and you will be able to access `timeS`.

Comment: thanks for the easy and short hint ;) I'm able now to further process the desired variable.